# Finding the sum of Numbers in a string containing letters and numbers using javascript & for loops

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, typeof

I think I'm close to solving this one The goal here is the find the Numbers in the string and add them together to find the sum of them.
there are numbers and letters in the strings in question

instruction:

- PART 2
- Create a getStringSum(str) function that returns the sum of any integers that are       in the string.
- Example1: getStringSum("GH2U87A") => 17
- Example2: getStringSum("GHIUJUHSG") => 0
- */

Where I'm at:

```
   function getStringSum(str) {
    let sum = 0;
     for(let  i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
      if (str[] == typeof Number){
      sum += str[i];
      };
      };
     return sum;
      };
```

I have my for loop condition set to iterate through the string, but I don't think my "typeof" proterty is registering the Numbers in the string as numbers, because theyre are within a string, I'm not certain thats the case, but I'm guessing thats whats happening, so my biggest question, is how to re assign the numbers, or identify the numbers in my string, to the value of number . any help or advice / push in the right direction is greatly apprecitated, thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1:** Split the string into an array

```
let str = "GHIUJUHSG"
let newStr = str.split('');
```

**Step 2:** Declare a variable to store your answer.

```
let answer = 0;
```

**Step 3:** Iterate through the array using forEach and try converting each element into an integer. If the conversion is successful add the element to the answer variable.

```
   newStr.forEach(item => {
        if(parseInt(item)){
            answer = answer + parseInt(item)
        }
    })
```

**Step 4:** Console.log your answer to see the answer.

```
console.log("answer: ", answer)
```

**Now, create a function to do this all for you:**

```
let str = "GHIUJUHSG"
const findNumberAndSum = (str) => {
    let answer = 0;
    str.split('').forEach(item =>{
        if(parseInt(item)){
            answer = answer + parseInt(item);
        }
    })
    return answer;
}
console.log(findNumberAndSum(str)) //The result should be 0 in case of "GHIUJUHSG" and 17 in case of "GH2U87A"
```

Comment: I really appreicate the step by step walk through that really helped me understand what was going on, were I am in my course we haven't covered the ".split" or ".forEach' or "parseInt" (not sure why ) but I'm glad you showed me how I can put those to use! already knocked out several other problems thanks to that, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what you think `str[] == typeof Number` means.

If you want to sum all integers in a string, you'll need to try to convert each character to a number, and only add them to the sum if they're not NaN. This is because `Number` will return `NaN` if it fails.

Either as a for loop:

```js
let sum = 0;
for (const c of str) {
    const num = Number(c);
    if (isNaN(num) continue;

    sum += num;
}
```

Or using the built-in functions:

```js
str.split("").map(Number).filter( (v) => !isNaN(v)).reduce( (acc, v) => acc + v, 0)
```